# User defined public variables yii2 model prints empty value

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i defined some values in my yii2 frontend user model, my model name is  'PhCabinetUser'
following is code from my model.

```
class PhCabinetUser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{


public $has_liveaccount;
public $email_verification;
public $account_deposited;
public $document_uploaded;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'ph_cabinet_user';
}
```

Now when i try to get $email_verification in my controller it returns empty value.

following is code from my controller.

```
$model = PhCabinetUser::find()->all();
    $row = array();

    foreach($model as $obj) {
  echo $obj['email_verification'];
  echo $obj->email_verification;
   }
```

however when i print $obj array it shows value for email_verification
following is my print_r($obj) result.

```
crm\models\PhCabinetUser Object ( [has_liveaccount] => [email_verification] => [account_deposited] => [document_uploaded] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 29 [company_id] => 1 [first_name] => Super [last_name] => Man [username] => ksdwpfr3.a4q@20email.eu [email] => ksdwpfr3.a4q@20email.eu [registration_email_token] => PXwTu8KULal2_So5U3wVllxfKg1X-Dzh_1468296370 [country] => 2 [country_code] => +355 [phone] => 1234567890 [dob] => [gender] => male [address1] => [address2] => [city] => [state] => [zipcode] => [source] => Website [owner] => 1 [lead_manager] => [has_liveaccount] => 0
```

> [email_verification] => 1

```
[account_deposited] => 0 
[document_uploaded] => 0 
[lead_status] => 1 
[status] => 10 
[created_at] => 1468296369 [updated_at] => 1468296580 ) 

[_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( 
[id] => 29 
[company_id] => 1 
[first_name] => Super 
[last_name] => Man 
[username] => ksdwpfr3.a4q@20email.eu 
[auth_key] => Nc-GABmcqJIpib22L5cuwgBaOKqRvbiQ 
[password_hash] => $2y$13$ZHB6IF51LODVqAEwI2zRkuIWbgEZ165acvpIeiVm2SZBFA1kzpp4S 
[password_reset_token] => 
[email] => ksdwpfr3.a4q@20email.eu 
[registration_email_token] => PXwTu8KULal2_So5U3wVllxfKg1X-Dzh_1468296370 
[country] => 2 
[country_code] => +355 
[phone] => 1234567890 
[dob] => 
[gender] => male 
[address1] => 
[address2] => 
[city] => 
[state] => 
[zipcode] => 
[source] => Website 
[owner] => 1 
[lead_manager] => 
[has_liveaccount] => 0 
[email_verification] => 1 
[account_deposited] => 0 
[document_uploaded] => 0 
[lead_status] => 1 
[status] => 10 
[created_at] => 1468296369 
[updated_at] => 1468296580 
) 
[_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
[_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
[_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
[_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) )
```

now how to get this value in a variable.

Comment: Rather then doing echo, check it once via var_dump it must be boolean I suppose

Comment: yes it is boolean variable. so how to print it?

Comment: why you are using member variable in `ActiveRecord` Class Model

Comment: Echo will not work on this. do var_dump and you can directly use it in if conditions

Comment: How to use it in if condition. i tried this if($obj['email_verification']==1) { echo "works"; }   but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the public vars you added ad the top of your class don't override  your ActiveRecord .. you have already the same var name in active record .. the declaration of a public  var in the model generate a fails in  assignement of the valeu and you get empty result  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
if($obj->email_verification) {
echo "Works";
}
```

Comment: what is the var_dump($obj->email_verification); result

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$model = PhCabinetUser::find()->all();
var_dump($model); exit;
```